# Segfault on 2.8 when switching to Cycles rendered viewport using bumblebee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view, error, linux

Some infos on my system:

- CPU: i5-4210U
- GPU: NVIDIA 840M
- OS: Debian 10 stable
- OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 418.74

This started to happen when I upgraded from Debian 9 to 10.
When I start Blender 2.80 (installed through snap, but happens even with the package downloaded from the site) using primusrun/optirun and then switch to Cycles' rendered viewport, Blender just crashes, closing.

Logging from terminal didn't show any error message, just a path to log file */tmp/blender.crash.txt*:

```
# Blender 2.80 (sub 75), Commit date: 2019-07-29 14:47, Hash f6cb5f54494e
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'RENDER'  # Property
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'  # Property
bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'  # Property

# backtrace
blenderb(BLI_system_backtrace+0x1d) [0x1369c1d]
blenderb() [0x1153279]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x37840) [0x7fc563a18840]
blenderb(GPU_texture_bind+0x6f) [0x40ff7bf]
blenderb(GPU_viewport_texture_pool_query+0xa7) [0x4103487]
blenderb() [0x2a227d3]
blenderb() [0x2a13851]
blenderb(DRW_draw_render_loop_ex+0x2e7) [0x2a14c77]
blenderb(view3d_main_region_draw+0x77) [0x2cdce07]
blenderb(ED_region_do_draw+0x851) [0x2d4ebf1]
blenderb(wm_draw_update+0x483) [0x1517513]
blenderb(WM_main+0x30) [0x1514c30]
blenderb(main+0x2fe) [0x10c0abe]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xeb) [0x7fc563a0509b]
blenderb() [0x114fb9c]
```

The backtracing seems to point that something's wrong when Blender tries to use/access libc.so.6
I ran it again using GDB, and the switching caused this error to pop up - a segfault happens, when GPUTexture is called:

```
GPUTexture: texture create failed

Thread 1 "blenderb" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000040ff7bf in GPU_texture_bind ()
```

Running it again with `--debug-all flag`, that's what happens when trying to activate rendered viewport:

```
Shader file written to disk: /tmp/blender_Me88xU/0095.vert
Shader file written to disk: /tmp/blender_Me88xU/0095.frag
GPUTexture: texture create failed
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault
```

What seems strange to me is that I don't get any crash or error when actually rendering with cycles+primusrun pressing F12

Comment: Even though this is likely not caused by Blender but an issue of OS and drivers, it may still be suited to ask on the official issue tracker. Perhaps some of the devs have experience with this specific setup. Also +1 great and detailed description. While I can't help you on this one, I'd be happy if all bug reports were written like that.